# How can I disable cache-redirector of `org.jetbrains.intellij` for some dependencies?

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to introduce `com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.58` in my plugin project, but when gradle resolve dependencies, the `org.jetbrains.intellij` plugin redirect the download request to https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/alibaba/fastjson/1.2.58/fastjson-1.2.58.pom, which is not exists.

How can I force gradle download this dependency from `mavenCentral` ?

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-plugin-service'
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.intellij" version "0.4.4"
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.58'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.intellij'
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

intellij {
    version ideaVersion
    updateSinceUntilBuild false
    plugins = [
            "com.jetbrains.php:${phpPluginVersion}",
            "com.jetbrains.php.blade:${bladePluginVersion}",
            'CSS',
            'java-i18n',
            'properties',
            'git4idea'
    ]
    pluginName 'tw tools'
}

patchPluginXml {
    sinceBuild '173'
}

group 'com.baiguiren'

version '1.2'

wrapper {
    gradleVersion '5.4.1'
}
```

Output of `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build`:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':prepareSandbox'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.58.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/alibaba/fastjson/1.2.58/fastjson-1.2.58.pom
         https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/alibaba/fastjson/1.2.58/fastjson-1.2.58.jar
         file:/Users/ruby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIU/2018.3.5/3abea719ce307bc4f573cba4e3d86f4e35cab07/ideaIU-2018.3.5/com.alibaba/fastjson/1.2.58/ivy-1.2.58.xml
         file:/Users/ruby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIU/2018.3.5/3abea719ce307bc4f573cba4e3d86f4e35cab07/ideaIU-2018.3.5/fastjson-1.2.58-withKotlin-withSources.xml
         file:/Users/ruby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIU/2018.3.5/3abea719ce307bc4f573cba4e3d86f4e35cab07/ideaIU-2018.3.5/com.alibaba/fastjson/1.2.58/fastjson-1.2.58.jar
         file:/Users/ruby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIU/2018.3.5/3abea719ce307bc4f573cba4e3d86f4e35cab07/ideaIU-2018.3.5/fastjson.jar
         file:/Users/ruby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/2018.3.5/78cbcd517ec112fbb0c7b45b00b464c1aa6371f3/fastjson-1.2.58-[classifier].jar
         https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/plugins.jetbrains.com/maven/com/alibaba/fastjson/1.2.58/fastjson-1.2.58.pom
         https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/plugins.jetbrains.com/maven/com/alibaba/fastjson/1.2.58/fastjson-1.2.58.jar
         file:/Users/ruby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/com.alibaba/fastjson-1.2.58.xml
         file:/Users/ruby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIU/2018.3.5/3abea719ce307bc4f573cba4e3d86f4e35cab07/ideaIU-2018.3.5/plugins/fastjson/fastjson.jar
         file:/Users/ruby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/fastjson-1.2.58/fastjson.jar
         file:/Users/ruby/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/2018.3.5/78cbcd517ec112fbb0c7b45b00b464c1aa6371f3/fastjson-2018.3.5.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I have tried to `Invalid caches and restart`, but not work.

I even tried to remove `org.jetbrains.intellij` plugin, but it's required by the project.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with cache-redirector, it's just one of the repositories registered in the project, Gradle checks them all.

Try to add the `mavenCentral` repo to your build.gradle (at the moment it's defined for `buildscript` only):

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: I have the same error. I have `mavenCentral()` in my repos. It checks the cache repo, but not the real repo, it seems.

Comment: It's important to check where `repositories` is declared. Make sure that yours is not in `buildscript` section  (or at least not only there), and that it's applied to the correct project or subproject. If you still have troubles with it, feel free to create an issue at https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/issues with build script content.